# Multi-Factor Authentication for users with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, office365, multi-factor-authentication

I have been trying to enable MFA (Multi Factor Authentication) for users on Office 365. When attempting to run below code I got the following the error. I tried different combinations related to this but no luck.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Module MSOnline

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'PASSWORD' -AsPlainText -Force
$LiveCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("admin@contoso.com", $password)
New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $LiveCred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

Connect-MsolService -Credential $Livecred

$st = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement
$st.RelyingParty = "*"
$st.State = "Enforced"
$sta = @($st)
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "user@contoso.com"  -StrongAuthenticationRequirements $sta
```

Error Message:

```
Property 'State' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At line:21 char:1
+ $st.State = "Enforced"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

Set-MsolUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'StrongAuthenticationRequirements'.
At line:23 char:59
+ Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "user@contoso.com"  -StrongAuthenticationR ...
+                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-MsolUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.SetUser
```

Comment: This is very strange, the [TechNet article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn194136(v=azure.98).aspx) on the cmdlet shows that parameter. Which version of Azure AD module are you using?

Comment: Windows Azure Active Directory Sync – April 2014 Builds Older Than 6765 So  I am using  the DirSyncConfigShell.psc1 that was located in:

C:\Program Files\Windows Azure Directory Sync

Comment: I would [try updating to the latest version](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28552.microsoft-azure-active-directory-powershell-module-version-release-history.aspx)

Comment: Is there any alternative method without version update?thanks